# How to include pagination within a function that displays a table from mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, pagination

I have this function that displays information from a mysql table and it works perfectly when i call it.

However, I am having trouble understanding how to alter it so that it includes pagination and not display everything within the table.

Here's the function's code:

```
function tabla_presupuestos() {
    $conexion_bd = conectar();

    $consulta = "
    SELECT d.idPre
         , em.nombre as doctor
         , pac.nombre as paciente
         , d.diagnostico
         , DATE_FORMAT(d.fechaEmision, '%M %e %Y') as fechaEmision
         , DATE_FORMAT(d.fechaVencimiento, '%M %e %Y') as DiasRestantes 
      FROM empleado em
         , paciente pac
         , presupuestodental d 
     WHERE em.idEmpleado = d.idEmpleado 
       AND pac.idPaciente = d.idPaciente 
     ORDER 
        BY fechaEmision
    ";

     $resultados_consulta = $conexion_bd->query($consulta);
     $resultado = '<div style="width:auto; margin:0 auto;"><table class="table table-striped">';
     $resultado .= '<thead bgcolor="lightblue"><tr><th scope="col">Doctor</th><th  scope="col">Paciente</th><th scope="col">Diagnostico</th><th scope="col">Fecha de Emisión</th><th scope="col">Vencimiento</th><th scope="col"> </th><tr></thead>';

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados_consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $resultado .= '<tbody><tr>';
        $resultado .= '<td>'.$row["doctor"].'</td>';
        $resultado .= '<td>'.$row["paciente"].'</td>';
        $resultado .= '<td><a href="editardiagnostico.php?idPre='.$row["idPre"].'">'.$row["diagnostico"].'</td>';
        $resultado .= '<td>'.$row["fechaEmision"].'</td>';
        $resultado .= '<td>'.$row["DiasRestantes"].'</td>';
        $resultado .= '<td><a href="borrar_presupuesto.php?idPre='.$row["idPre"].'"><button class="btn btn-danger">Ocultar</button></a></td>';
        $resultado .= '</tr>';
     }
        $resultado .= '</tbody></table></div>';
        desconectar($conexion_bd);
        return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: So you need a LIMIT clause in the query and some prev next buttons/links whatever that track the next batch you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this three things:

1. Adding `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to the query.
2. Getting total rows.
3. Adding paginations button.

In order to add pagination, you have to limit the data displaying, and it is better to get limited data from the database, so I added `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to your query:

```
SELECT d.idPre,
    em.nombre as doctor,
    pac.nombre as paciente,
    d.diagnostico,
    DATE_FORMAT(d.fechaEmision, '%M %e %Y') as fechaEmision,
    DATE_FORMAT(d.fechaVencimiento, '%M %e %Y') as DiasRestantes
FROM empleado em, paciente pac, presupuestodental d 
WHERE 
    em.idEmpleado=d.idEmpleado AND 
    pac.idPaciente=d.idPaciente 
ORDER BY fechaEmision
LIMIT ? OFFSET?
```

Then, you need to get total rows that are presentable and divide it by the rows displaying each time to get total pages. So this is the query for that(you may need to change it in order to get the correct rows count):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM empleado em, paciente pac, presupuestodental d 
WHERE 
    em.idEmpleado=d.idEmpleado AND 
    pac.idPaciente=d.idPaciente
```

And now to add pagination, let's complete your function. I changed your codes a little in order to clean it:

```
/*
    Counting all rows
*/
function rowCount($db) {
    $query = "
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM empleado em, paciente pac, presupuestodental d 
        WHERE 
            em.idEmpleado=d.idEmpleado AND 
            pac.idPaciente=d.idPaciente";
        
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
    return $stmt->fetch();
}

/*
    Creating pagintaion links
*/
function pagination($currentPage, $totalPages) {
    $html = '
    <ul>';
    
    for ($page = 0; $page < $totalPages;$page++)
        if ($page == $currentPage)
            $html .= '
        <li>' . $page . '</li>';
        else
            $html .= '
        <li>
            <a href="{the table page link}/' . $page . '>' . $page . '</a>
        </li>';
        
    $html .= '
    </ul>';
    
    return $html;
}

/*
    The page which should be displayed will be taken as a parameter
*/
function tabla_presupuestos($page = 0) {
    // This is the number if row you want to display
    $rowsPerPage = 10;
    $totalPages = rowCount($conexion_bd)/$rowsPerPage;

    $conexion_bd = conectar();

    $consulta = "
        SELECT d.idPre,
            em.nombre as doctor,
            pac.nombre as paciente,
            d.diagnostico,
            DATE_FORMAT(d.fechaEmision, '%M %e %Y') as fechaEmision,
            DATE_FORMAT(d.fechaVencimiento, '%M %e %Y') as DiasRestantes
        FROM empleado em, paciente pac, presupuestodental d 
        WHERE 
            em.idEmpleado=d.idEmpleado AND 
            pac.idPaciente=d.idPaciente
        ORDER BY fechaEmision
        LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";

    $stmt = $conexion_bd->prepare($consulta);
    
    // binding LIMIT and OFFSET to the query
    $stmt->bind_param($rowsPerPage, $rowsPerPage*$page);
    
    // executing statement and getting the result
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    $resultado = '
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Doctor</th>
                    <th  scope="col">Paciente</th>
                    <th scope="col">Diagnostico</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha de Emisión</th>
                    <th scope="col">Vencimiento</th>
                <tr>
            </thead>';

     while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $resultado .= '
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>' . $row["doctor"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["paciente"] . '</td>
                    <td><a href="editardiagnostico.php?idPre=' . $row["idPre"] . '">' . $row["diagnostico"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["fechaEmision"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["DiasRestantes"] . '</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="borrar_presupuesto.php?idPre=' . $row["idPre"] . '">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">Ocultar</button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
     }
        $resultado .= '
            </tbody>
        </table>
        ' . pagination($page, $totalPages) . '
    </div>';
    
    desconectar($conexion_bd);
    return $resultado;
}
```